# Implementing LINQ-Style Extension Method on Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: c#, arrays, extension-methods

I have some code that works with a two-dimensional grid (array) and I ended up with a lot of routines that loop through each item in the grid.

But I thought it would be nice if I could do this LINQ-style using extension methods.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
private static void ForEach(this MyType[,] grid, Action<MyType> action)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < grid.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
            action(grid[row, col]);
}
```

**1.** Intellisense doesn't seem to recognize this extension method on an object of type `MyType[3,3]`. Am I missing something about writing an extension method for a two-dimensional array?

**2.** What is the recommended way to implement such a pattern that allows me to conditionally set the grid value? Using the code above, setting the passed value would not affect the original array.

**EDIT:**

Okay, after originally implementing this extension method within the same class it was called from, I stupidly left it declared as `private` when I moved it to an external class. I guess it won't work as a private method in the same class and it obviously won't work as a private method in an external class.

Would still love to see an answer to number 2 though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't mean `private`

Comment: D'oh! That was it. I originally had the extension method in the same class and made it private but when I moved it to an external class, looks like I forgot to change it. Duh!

Comment: Just so it's clear, you _can_ make the extension method `private` and it will still work as an extension method within the static class you defined, it's just not externally accessible. Though there's very little point in doing this.

Comment: Is this extension necessary?  You can just do `foreach(MyType item in grid) {action(item);}`

Comment: @JeffMercado: Actually, that's what I did originally but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: As for #2, you could try a `Func<MyType,MyType>` instead of an Action and set the value explicitly. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by set the value conditionally, or what the Action would be doing to the value though.

Comment: OT, just nitpicking: When using `UpperBound()` the also start with the `LowerBound()`. But more commonly: `for(i = 0; i < grid.GetLength(0); i++)`

Comment: @DStanley: Interesting, I didn't realize `foreach` works with arrays with multiple dimensions. I may play with that, although it may not be useful for this project because I will probably need to know the row, column value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question, an Action will not work because it does not return a value, so it could not directly update the array.  What you may want is a `Func<MyType,MyType>` that will take in the original value, do some processing, and return a *new* value that your ForEach will then plop back into the array.  If you need to know the row and column then make it a `Func<MyType, int, int>`.

As a side note, I would not call it `ForEach` since you are modifying the underlying collection (which `ForEach` cannot do in a normal collection).  I would call it `UpdateAll` or something like that.

So you end up with something like:

```
public static void UpdateAll(this MyType[,] grid, Func<MyType,MyType> action)
{
    for (int row = grid.GetLowerBound(0); row <= grid.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
        for (int col = grid.GetLowerBound(1); col <= grid.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
            grid[row, col] = action(grid[row, col]);
}
```

Note that it uses `GetLowerBound` and uses `<=` instead of `<` on the upper bound check.

Comment: Yes, `ForEach` was intended for the routine that didn't change the values. The issue for me is that, depending on the current item, I may or may not want to change it. So I was hoping for an approach where I didn't need to set it if it wasn't needed. But perhaps this suggestion is the best and I'll just have to return the original value if I don't want to change it.